# Can it be a wrong given CIDR?

Tags: ip-address, subnet, cidr

Am given some homework about creating 4 sub-nets out of a network address of 198.77.48.0/23. Clearly this is a class C address but can it even be possible to have a CIDR /23? 
We took it otherwise and thought our tutor might have errored. That in order to create 4 sub-nets, we actually need a /26. In that way, we get the following sub-nets

### Network addresses

198.77.48.0 -> 198.77.48.64 -> 198.77.48.128 -> 198.77.48.192

### Hosts addresses : From

198.77.48.1 -> 198.77.48.65 -> 198.77.48.129 -> 198.77.48.193

### Hosts addresses To

198.77.48.62 -> 198.77.48.126 -> 198.77.48.190 -> 198.77.48.254

### Broadcast addresses

198.77.48.63 -> 198.77.48.127 -> 198.77.48.191 -> 198.77.48.255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i finally got the answer. This is like sub-netting an already sub-netted network.

Comment: Nor your question, nor your answer makes sense .. a `/23` subnet mask can be divided into 4 equal subnets by using a `/25` subnet mask.. So you take the `198.77.48.0/23` network and divide it into 4 equal subnets with `126 usable hosts` in each subnet.